# React: Object is not a function or its value is not iterable

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, use-effect

I try to building an app using hooks and I've spend a lot of time to solve this problem:

`TypeError: Object is not a function or its return value is not iterable`

This is my code:

```
import { Button } from 'react-bootstrap';
import BookSearch from "./BookSearch";
import React from 'react';
import { useState, useEffect, response, useForm } from 'react';
const query = 'harry potter';

const Books = () => {
    const [values, handleChange] = useForm({ 
        books: '', 
        bookName: ''
    });

    useEffect(() => {
        console.log("render");
    }, [values.bookName]);
    
        return (
            <div>
            <div class="search-area">
            <form action="">
            <input value={values.bookName} onChange={handleChange} type="text"></input>
            <Button type="submit" variant="danger">Search</Button>
            </form>
            </div>
            </div>
        )
}

export default Books;
```

Console says that erros is in this line:

`const [values, handleChange] = useForm({`

I already searched, spend a lot time and didn't found the solution to this error. What can I do?

Comment: React doesn't have an export named `useForm`. Are you trying to import from some other library?

Comment: @NicholasTower Before I had an error that said "response is not defined" and I tried this, so worked.

Comment: Your issue is that you're importing things from the wrong library. react does not have a `useForm` export, nor a `response` export. I don't know what library you're trying to use, so i cannot make a specific recommendation until i know that.

Comment: @NicholasTower That I solved. I just typed `npm i react-hook-form` and `import { useForm } from "react-hook-form"`. But my problem with `Object is not a function` remain.

Comment: [useForm](https://react-hook-form.com/api/useform) from react-hook-form does not return an array, so `[values, handleChange] = useForm` is the wrong way to destructure it.

Comment: @NicholasTower So perhaps can I use `useState` or no? I've tried now and seems that's worked, but it's really correct?

Comment: I guess you should figure out what you want your code to do before you go trying a bunch of random things. Official docs are usually a good resource. Here's the [useForm hook docs](https://react-hook-form.com/api/useform) to help understand what is passed to the hook (*a configuration object*) and what is returned for use by your code.

Comment: Right, thanks. My problems was solved!